# API or other queryable source for getting total NiFi queued data

Tags: api, apache-nifi

Is there an API point or whatever other queryable source where I can get the total queued data?:

[image: NiFi header]

setting up a little dataflow in NiFi to monitor NiFi itself sounds sketchy, but if it's a common practice, let's be it. Anyway, I cannot find the API endpoint to get that total

**Note:** I have a single NiFi instance: I don't have nor will implement S2S reporting since I am on a single instance, single node NiFi setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Site-to-Site Reporting tasks were developed because they work for clustered, standalone, and multiple instances thereof. You'd just need to put an Input Port on your canvas and have the reporting task send to that.

An alternative as of NiFi 1.10.0 (via [NIFI-6780](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6780)) is to get the nifi-sql-reporting-nar and use QueryNiFiReportingTask, you can use a SQL query to get the metrics you want. That uses a RecordSinkService controller service to determine how to send the results, there are various implementations such as Site-to-Site, Kafka, Database, etc. The NAR is not included in the standard NiFi distribution due to size constraints, but you can get the latest version (1.11.4) [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/nifi/nifi-sql-reporting-nar/1.11.4/nifi-sql-reporting-nar-1.11.4.nar), or change the URL to match your NiFi version.

Comment: Thanks @mattyb! didn't know the S2S strategy wasn't overkill for a standalone NiFi instance, and for sure I'll give the SQL Reporting NAR a try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

@jonayreyes You can find information about how to get queue data from NiFi API Here:

[NiFi Rest API - FlowFile Count Monitoring](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/NiFi-REST-API-FlowFile-Count-Monitoring/ta-p/244208)

Comment: Thanks @steven-dfheinz but even when that works, it does so over existing connections,  and I want all the connections, this is, the global number under the service's logo